# React native white screen when i build my apk with firebase

Tags: android, react-native, build, firebase-cloud-messaging, apk

i have a problem when i build an apk using the command expo build:android. I've got a white screen. It seems the problem is related to firebase because i had to add react native fcm to receive notifications on my app. When i comment everything related to fcm/firebase (androidmanifest, build.gradle...) my apk works. The problem is idk where i can see the errors, what i am missing because i  followed all the tutorial on the react native firebase website to install cloud messaging. If you have an idea it would really help me, thanks in advance.

this is the tutorial in question : https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

I tried many times to modify the dependencies in build gradle, add new things i found in internet on the manifest, change versions... nothing works :(

Comment: https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage  expect to be used with Bare React Native CLI. How you are using it with Expo. Did you eject or use the Expo Custom Dev client?

Answer (score 0):

try checking your Android studio logs which shows red color highlighted text in it while running the react-native application. Hope that helps you in finding the problem.